# Hide parameter sent via POST request

Tags: php, laravel, registration, mailgun, one-time-password

I am making a registration wherein users inputs email as their username and I have to send a random code to their email after a successful registration.

So far, what I got is:

- **Step 1:** User registers with their email.
- **Step 2:** API Generates a random code and inserts it to my database table `(tbl_temp_otp)`.
- **Step 3:** After inserting to the database, the code will be sent to the email provided in the registration.
- **Step 4:** User gets the code, and input it into the registration form then API checks if that code exists and is still in `unused`
  state.

So far, it works.

My issue is that, how can I send the OTP code through POST request without anybody seeing it in the `network` tab in google chrome?

**EDIT based on the comments**

I think I explained the issue in a wrong way...

 What I really meant was not `without anybody seeing it` but `without the registrant seeing it`.

Since, the registrant is able to see the code inserted in the database, I'm concerned that they'll register with a non-existing email address and verify it by looking into the `network` tab and input the inserted OTP code and still able to completely register with the provided non-existing email address.

Comment: _“how can I send the OTP code through POST request without anybody seeing it in the network tab in google chrome?”_ – You can’t. Why did you think this was necessary?

Comment: `without anybody seeing it`...assuming you use HTTPS, the only person who can see it is the user, and it's their token so that doesn't matter. I agree with all the other comments and answers so far, this is a total non-issue. Also, if it's genuinely a **one-time**-password, then by the time it's sent in the POST, assuming your server receives and processes it successfully, then it will count as used and can't be used again. So even if someone _did_ intercept it at that moment, it shouldn't matter. There's a slight chance of the email containing it going astray, but again, a small risk.

Comment: Re your edit: As a concern, this makes even less sense than before. You say "without the registrant seeing it". But that's impossible, partly because they always have access to the Network tab, but mainly because **they typed it into the form in the first place**! You yourself said `User gets the code, and input it into the registration form`. So they already know the code! If you hide it from them, the whole process becomes impossible to implement. I don't think you have thought through the logic of what you're saying.

Comment: Furthermore...in your database, that OTP code should be associated with a specific registration attempt, and therefore a specific email address (the one the code was sent to). It should therefore be _impossible_ for anyone to register it to a different email address. Submitting it should only activate the email address it was originally associated with. If it's possible to use it to activate a different email address, then you have a serious flaw in your server-side logic. That has nothing to do with the contents of the form's POST data.

Comment: And also, as I said previously, if the user submits the code in the form, and the server accepts it, then since you said it's a one-time password, it should not be possible to use that code again, either to activate the same email or a different one. Again, if it's possible to do that, you have another serious flaw in your server-side logic. And again, that has nothing to do with the contents of the form's POST data.

Comment: Lastly, it's unclear why you even need a form for this. If you've ever activated an account by email, you'll have seen that mostly they don't make you copy and paste the OTP code. Mostly, the email simply contains a link which already has the code in the URL. e.g. the link might point to `https://www.example.com/activate.php?code=879845SSSDWE3G48S97F42A32387`. That way, the user clicks on the link, and it immediately navigates to that URL, the PHP script sees the OTP code in the $_GET parameters, and instantly checks it and activates the account, without the user having to do any more input.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to hide the OTP that is sent through a POST request. The best thing to do, is to make the OTP time-based, and limit the duration that it is valid for.
Anyways, the request that is visible in the network tab is only visible for the respective user, so there is no actual security risk. Hope this clarifies your question. You can continue with the same process.

Comment: Hello @Aditya, I made an edit. I hope it'll give new perspective about the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

You are sending it by email where the email client needs to read it, then it needs to be transferred to the user's browser so the browser can send it back over the network.

The user's browser and email client belong to the user. They are under the user's control. They can't be used to conceal information from the user.

---

But that shouldn't matter. It is a one time code designed to prove that the user is who they claim to be. It doesn't matter if the user gets their hands on it.

---

There's a risk that it might be intercepted between the browser and your server, but you can mitigate that by using HTTPS.

There's a risk that it might be intercepted between the email client and the browser, but there isn't anything you can do about the possibility of the user having malware on their system which is designed to share your one time password. It's a pretty remote possibility in the first place though.

There's a risk that the email will be intercepted, but nothing you can do about that unless you want to force the user to invest in setting up and learning how to use GPG or similar. (Again, it is a small risk).

---

Re edit:

> I'm concerned that they'll register with a non-existing email address and verify it by looking into the network tab

Your one-time code should be associated with the email address that it was emailed to.

It won't show up in the network tab until the user clicks the link in that email. So there is no way for them to get the code without the email address being real.

You've already associated the code with a particular email address in your database, so they can't change their mind and use that code with a different email address.

Comment: `you can mitigate that by using HTTP`...assume you meant HTTPS? :-)

Comment: Oops, typo. Fixed.

Comment: Hello good sir, I made an edit. I hope it'll give new perspective about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your flow itself may be incorrect. The proper way to do your flow is as follows :

1. Get the email id the user enters in your form.
2. When the user clicks a verify button, send the email id to your backend
3. Generate a random otp code against that email IN YOUR BACKEND
4. Store OTP & EMAIL & TIMESTAMP as an entry in your backend database
5. Send the otp via the EMAIL IN THE DB ENTRY
6. Ask the user to verify OTP by checking his email and pasting the OTP in your form
7. Then User submits form - In the backend, both OTP & email are used together to retrieve the db entry, and if it is found, and is within X amount of time from timestamp - EMAIL FROM THE DATABASE ENTRY is registered against the user account
8. Set a periodic database purge process to remove all entries with timestamp older than X amount of time. NOTE - if using REDIS, you can even set the entry to auto expire after X time, so this step + timestamp is not needed at all.

If in the middle of this process, the user changes the email id at anytime, whether in the form or through some hacks, the db entry will not be found and OTP will never verify.

This way it is impossible for the user to manipulate his email id after the fact. If for whatever reason, the user suddenly wishes to change their email id, the entire flow must restart.